# How to enumerate elements for each foreign key

Tags: python, django, sqlite

friends.

I have 2 classes (part and data). To each element of class Part there are several elements of class Data (via foreign key). So, I have 2 tables in SQLite: Part and Data. The ID numbering in the Data table is continuous, that is, regardless of whether the foreign key has changed, the table ID is incremented. How to number the table for each foreign key independently (from 1 to the number of rows with one foreign key)?
By the way,  English is foreign language :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not get your questions exactly, But You want to get all data objects related to a particular part object then you can use below code

```
p = Part.objects.filter().first()
# datas is a list of data objects associated to part p
datas = list(p.data_set.all())
```

Updated

If you want to enumerate on all objects of Part which are used a foreign key in Data table use below code:

```
# Assuming your foreign key in data table has name 'part'
Part.objects.filter(id__in=Data.objects.values_list('part', flat=True))
```

Comment: Not that it is too relevant, Grammarly passes all your data to their servers. So be careful if you are working on confidential documents. sorry for the tangent

Comment: @Morpheus Thanks for letting me know, will remember during writing in the confidential doc. Is my answer helpfull to you?